# How do I programmatically toggle from a primary tab to a secondary tab using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle from a primary tab to a secondary tab using jQuery and JavaScript.
eg I have 2 primary tabs A and B . I have 2 secondary tabs C and D inside tab B. I want to toggle to tab D from tab A on click of a event. How can I do this??

Comment: Hi, can you please post your code and what have you tried to achieve the same?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Impossible to know what your tab structure is to help you.... If you showed a basic example of tabs and how you show them than we could help.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for that. You can do it with CSS and the [`:target` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your html looks like this

```
<div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab Adunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab C</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">

            <button onClientClick="openChaild()">
                Open chaild tab
            </button>

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>tab 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">

            <div class="Innertabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Chaild tab a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Chaild tab B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Chaild tab C</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1">
                    <p>sub tab 1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2">
                    <p>sub tab 2.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-3">
                    <p>sub tab 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
```

and you achieve your goal like

```
 $( function() {
    $( ".tabs" ).tabs();
     $( ".Innertabs" ).tabs();



  } );

  function openChaild()
  {
         $(".tabs" ).tabs( { active: 2 } );
      $(".Innertabs" ).tabs( { active: 1 } );
  }
```

Please mark as answer if this works for you.